# Android unregister receiver but still receiving

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered receiver on onCreate method of Service and unregister it onDestroy? It works perfectly, but on certain Samsung Galaxy s3 i still recives receiver even i stopped service. How to find a solution? is it possible? Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
package com.sms.sendsms.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Navruz on 30.03.2016.
*/
public class SendSmsService extends Service {

private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendSmsService.class);

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LOGGER.info("Service is onCreate");
    registerReceiver(incomingCallReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED));


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    LOGGER.info("Service is onStartCommand");

    return START_STICKY;

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();        
    unregisterReceiver(incomingCallReceiver);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private BroadcastReceiver incomingCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LOGGER.info("IncomingCallReceiver is received.");
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                LOGGER.info("state : " + state);

            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Uraaaaa:)))))))) I have found a solution. The problem was telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(), ..) not reciver. All i need to do is that telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); onDestroy method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to call `unregisterReceiver(...)` in `onDestroy()` since it is not **always** guaranteed to be called.

From [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can
>   happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called
>   finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this
>   instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between
>   these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.
>
> **Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data!** For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

References:

1. [Android Activity onDestroy() is not always called and if called only part of the code is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361719/android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the)
2. [Activity OnDestroy never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called)
3. [Is ondestroy not always called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608948/is-ondestroy-not-always-called)

**EDIT**

Ok so just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14147909/5352802) from @CommonsWare where it says that `Service`'s `onDestroy()` will not get called in some situations as:

> - If the user Force Stops you from the Settings app
> - If Android needs RAM in a hurry (e.g., to process an incoming phone
>     call) and elects to terminate your process to free up that RAM
> - You terminate the process from DDMS
> - Also, if your service crashes with an unhandled exception somewhere,
>     Android may consider the service to be defunct and skip `onDestroy()`

I guess you are either force stopping the `Service` or the device is running low on RAM; and hence `onDestroy()` is not being called.

Comment: Yes because, most of the times it is called. But not **always**.

Comment: Even Servise has not onPause method? Have you ever used receivers in Service?

Comment: @nAkhmedov Ok my bad, I removed that part but still it is true (even in case of `Service`) that `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting problem in some device you can try disabling the receiver component explicitly..This will do same regardless of what has specified in manifest.

BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class Reg extends BroadcastReceiver{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // your stuff
  }
}
```

call this at onDestroy()

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this,"com.example.Reg");    //package name,broadcast receiver class path
PackageManager pkg = this.getPackageManager();
pkg.setComponentEnabledSetting(comp,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

add this to manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.Reg" />
```

[COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED)

[ENABLING DISABLING BROADCAST RECEIVER DURING RUNTIME](http://code4reference.com/2012/08/enabling-disabling-broadcast-receiver-during-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, it works for me:

```
/**
 * if service is going to destroy, unregister broadcast receiver by main activity context.
 */
@Override 
public void onDestroy() {
Log.e(TAG, ">>>>>UEventObserverService.onDestroy()");
getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(screen_state_receiver);
super.onDestroy();
}
```